# Why My Code always show @vue/composition-api/dist/vue-composition-api.mjs Not Found?

Tags: vue.js, npm, vuejs2

I have one project which given by my vendor.

Its a Vue.js project.

I already downloaded all the package needed using `npm install`
But when I tried to run `npm run dev` why its always give me Error Message :
This dependency was not found:

- @vue/composition-api/dist/vue-composition-api.mjs in ./node_modules/vue-demi/lib/index.mjs

But I already installed the package mentioned above.

Any clue should I follow please? already tried to remove all the package and then re-installed it, still error.

Thank you

Here is my package.json :

```
{
  "name": "vuexy-nuxt",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "node node_modules/nuxt/bin/nuxt.js",
    "build": "node node_modules/nuxt/bin/nuxt.js build",
    "start": "node node_modules/nuxt/bin/nuxt.js start",
    "generate": "node node_modules/nuxt/bin/nuxt.js generate && yarn fix:html",
    "fix:html": "node tools/fix-index.js",
    "lint:js": "eslint --ext \".js,.vue\" --ignore-path .gitignore .",
    "lint": "yarn lint:js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@casl/ability": "4.1.6",
    "@casl/vue": "1.1.1",
    "@fullcalendar/daygrid": "5.5.0",
    "@fullcalendar/interaction": "5.5.0",
    "@fullcalendar/list": "5.5.0",
    "@fullcalendar/timegrid": "5.5.0",
    "@fullcalendar/vue": "5.5.0",
    "@mv-template/cameravision": "^0.0.2",
    "@nuxtjs/auth": "^4.9.1",
    "@nuxtjs/axios": "^5.13.1",
    "@nuxtjs/composition-api": "^0.23.2",
    "@nuxtjs/sentry": "^5.1.4",
    "@syncfusion/ej2-base": "^19.1.64",
    "@syncfusion/ej2-data": "^19.1.58",
    "@syncfusion/ej2-dropdowns": "^19.1.69",
    "@syncfusion/ej2-vue-charts": "^19.1.69",
    "@syncfusion/ej2-vue-diagrams": "^19.1.69",
    "@syncfusion/ej2-vue-grids": "^19.1.69",
    "@syncfusion/ej2-vue-inputs": "^19.1.67",
    "@syncfusion/ej2-vue-navigations": "^19.1.69",
    "@vue/composition-api": "^1.7.1",
    "@vue/runtime-dom": "^3.2.45",
    "@vueuse/core": "4.9.0",
    "animate.css": "4.1.1",
    "apexcharts": "3.23.0",
    "bootstrap": "4.6.0",
    "bootstrap-vue": "2.21.1",
    "chart.js": "2.9.4",
    "core-js": "^3.9.1",
    "echarts": "4.8.0",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "mv-template": "^0.0.96",
    "nuxt": "^2.15.3",
    "nuxt-i18n": "^6.26.0",
    "nuxtjs-mdi-font": "^1.0.2",
    "portal-vue": "2.1.7",
    "postcss-rtl": "1.7.3",
    "prismjs": "1.19.0",
    "replace-in-file": "^6.2.0",
    "rimraf": "^3.0.2",
    "sass": "^1.32.11",
    "sass-loader": "10",
    "swiper": "5.4.5",
    "uuid": "^8.3.2",
    "vee-validate": "3.4.5",
    "vue-apexcharts": "1.6.0",
    "vue-autosuggest": "2.2.0",
    "vue-chartjs": "3.5.0",
    "vue-cleave-component": "2.1.3",
    "vue-context": "6.0.0",
    "vue-echarts": "5.0.0-beta.0",
    "vue-feather-icons": "5.1.0",
    "vue-flatpickr-component": "8.1.6",
    "vue-form-wizard": "0.8.4",
    "vue-good-table": "2.21.0",
    "vue-perfect-scrollbar": "0.2.1",
    "vue-prism-component": "1.1.1",
    "vue-qrcode-reader": "^3.0.0",
    "vue-ripple-directive": "2.0.1",
    "vue-select": "3.11.2",
    "vue-sweetalert2": "^4.3.1",
    "vue-toastification": "1.7.8",
    "vuedraggable": "2.24.3",
    "vuex-persistedstate": "^4.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@nuxtjs/dotenv": "^1.4.1",
    "@nuxtjs/eslint-config": "^6.0.0",
    "@nuxtjs/eslint-module": "^3.0.2",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "eslint": "^7.22.0",
    "eslint-plugin-nuxt": "^2.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^7.7.0",
    "vue-server-renderer": "^2.6.12",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.12"
  },
  "peerDependencies": {
    "vue": "2.6.12"
  }
}
```

UPDATE :
After several times trying to re install npm package using `npm install`, now the error message is :

```
Package subpath './dist/vue-composition-api.esm.js' is not defined by "exports" in projectname\node_modules\@vue\composition-api\package.json
```

Comment: You should probably move `vue` into `dependencies` instead of `peer-dependencies`. You could also upgrade to Vue 2.7.14, and get rid of `@vue/composition-api`.

Vue 2.7 release info: https://blog.vuejs.org/posts/vue-2-7-naruto.html

Comment: just want to make sure, if I upgrade to Vue 2.7.14, I also need to upgrade vue-server-renderer to 2.7.14 also @RussDeneychuk ?

Comment: Not familiar with it, but generally yes, all plugins in Vue family need to be on same version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this issue with `yarn`.
I removed all the `node_module` folder and run `yarn install` instead of `npm install`